# Best way to define functions on JavaScript prototypes

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

Is there more elegant way to define functions on prototypes than in the code below? Ideally you would define everything inside Vector function.

```
var Vector = function (x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
};

Vector.prototype.plus = function (vector) {
    return new Vector (this.x + vector.x, this.y + this.y);
};

Vector.prototype.minus = function (vector) {
    return new Vector (this.x - vector.x, this.y - vector.y);
};

Object.defineProperty(Vector.prototype, "length", {
    get: function () {
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.x, 2) + Math.pow(this.y, 2));
    }
});

var vt = new Vector(3, 4);
var vt2 = new Vector(5, 6);
```

Comment: "Ideally you would define everything inside Vector function." Is this a wish, a guess, an answer, ...?

Comment: I don't define any functions inside my constructor.

Comment: Yes, use [ES6 Classes](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#classes); otherwise, no.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Unfortunately support is pretty bad at the moment: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#class

Comment: @JamesThorpe: ES6 classes are only minimally supported, as of yet.

Comment: @idmean [babeljs](https://babeljs.io/) - done.

Comment: @idmean You could call it a wish. And yes, I meant on ES5. This will have to do then, thanks guys.

Comment: @idmean Indeed - but in the meantime there are transpilers.